# How to make two row slider in PHP

Tags: php, slider

I have a design of two row slider in PHP with single foreach loop
I want to make dynamic this design like [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgxa9.png)
with PHP. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: for making dynamic use php + Mysql Query.

Comment: solve what and where's your code? have you tried anything, anything at all? we're not going to guess or code it for you, remember that.

Comment: <?php 
  foreach($stores as $rec) { ?>
       <!--- My design code is here --->
  <div >
     <!---- first row code --->
       <!--- second row code -->
</div>
<?php } ?>

Answer (score 0):

@FunkFortyNiner is right that you really need to expand on your question.  Because of that, this answer has to be vague and may be off point, but here is something that should be in the right direction:

```
<div id="slider">
<?php foreach($stores as $rec) : ?>
    <div class="slide">
    <a href="<?= $rec['link']; ?>">
        <img src="<?= $rec['image_src']; ?>" />
        <p><?= $rec['tagline']; ?></p>
    </a>
    <a class="button" href-"<?= $rec['link']; ?>"><?= $rec['button_label']; ?></a>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Its for only one row.How can I get two rows here ?

Comment: That's all in your CSS.  Without more information I can't give a full example, but I would use [Flexbox Styles](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).  Otherwise, you could use a table, but there would likely be issues with responsive-design and variable number of items in your rows.